# Extracting image filename with extension from string that includes file path and other random text

Tags: python, html, filenames

I am using python to create a list of images used in my website, along with the page in which they are used. I can extract the page, but I can't figure out how to extract the image filenames.  The examples of regular expressions I've looked at require the input to be just the path, but many of my html pages contain links to images that are embedded in a paragraph.  My guess is that I need to somehow extract just the path from the text string, then extract the filename from the path, but I can't figure out how to do it.

As for file structure of the site, all my images are in the same folder, so that never changes.  However, I have about 5000 pages that need scanning and the image links could show up almost anywhere from a paragraph to a list or table.

Here's my code so far:

```
    '''
    f = open(html_filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    file_str = f.readlines() 
    f.close() 

    img = 'img'

    # Open the file for writing.
    f = open('link_list.txt','a', encoding="utf-8")
    for line in file_str: 
        if img in line: 
            f.write(line + ', ' + html_filename)
    f.close()
    '''
```

An example output is this:

```
    '''
    <img src="../../Resources/Images/top.png" />, page_one.htm
    <img src="../../Resources/Images/bottom.png" />, page_two.htm
    <p>Next, either double-click in Column A, or click <img alt="" border="0" src="..\..\Resources\IMAGES\ICON.png" style="border: none;" />  to search for it.</p>, page_three.htm
    '''
```

What I am trying to get it this:

```
    '''
    top.png, page_one.htm
    bottom.png, page_two.htm
    ICON.png, page_three.htm
    etc.
    '''
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `BeautifulSoup` module to extract them. Here is an example -

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

with open('index.html', 'r') as f:

    contents = f.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')

    for el in soup.findAll('img'):
        print(os.path.split(el['src'])[-1])
```

Here is the output on a HTML file.

```sh
profile.png
project-featured.jpg
project-sdc.png
```